# Stop Javascript function after 5 seconds/ set .Blur() after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, video.js

I'm trying to get a button to lose focus after 5 seconds using .Blur() but using setTimeout and setInterval aren't working with the code I'm using.

I'm using VideoJS to get the time in the video, and between 1 and 10 seconds, the button with ID of 'butt6' should change to focused which is working.
The issue I'm experiencing is *unfocusing* after 5 seconds.

In the code, I have got between 1 and 10 seconds, and I've got the setTimeout set to 5 seconds to test whether it was working but it isn't and am currently relying on an elseif .blur() to lose focus after the 10 seconds is up.

I've scoured the internet trying to find someone else who may have had a similar issue but everything I've tried so far either doesn't focus the button or doesn't un-focus at all.

Code is below:

```
var myPlayer = document.getElementById('my_video_1');
var myFunc = function(){
    var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime; 
    if (whereYouAt > 1 && whereYouAt <= 10){
       var linkToFocus = document.getElementById('butt6');
       linkToFocus.focus();
       setTimeout(function(){ linktoFocus.blur(); }, 5000);
    }
    elseif (whereYouAt > 11){
    linkToFocus.blur();
}
myPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate',myFunc,false);
```

Comment: have you tried to set focus on another element to make it loose focus?

Comment: I have yes.  The original code ran through 4 buttons, focusing each of them after a 3 second interval.  Ideally, I'd like to only focus for a few seconds, then remove focus. But having more than one if function doesn't focus anything

Comment: `mPlayer.currentTime` looks like a method that needs to be called.  [reference](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#MethodscurrentTime)

Comment: Do you want the button to blur 5 seconds after the first time it's focused and then never re-focus or do you want the button to focus during the first 10 seconds of the video and display a minimum of 5 seconds?  Your question and code sample are contradicting.  Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I rushed trying to type this last night.  
When the video player reaches a specific time, I need the button to highlight as it will be referred to in the video - I'd put in 10 seconds to test whether the setTimeout was working or not, but would need the button to focus for a maximum of 5 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the `if` keep executing and focusing after the `setTimeout`. This should solve:

```
var myPlayer = document.getElementById('my_video_1');
var hasFocus = false;
var myFunc = function(){
    var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime; 
    if (whereYouAt > 1 && whereYouAt <= 10 && !hasFocus){
       var linkToFocus = document.getElementById('butt6');
       linkToFocus.focus();
       hasFocus = true;
       setTimeout(function(){ linktoFocus.blur(); }, 5000);
    }
}
myPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate',myFunc,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion Tiago, and apologies for the delay in responding.
The 'setTimeout' didn't work unfortunately, but using .blur() I managed to take focus away from the buttons and formatted with pseudo classes in CSS for transition.

My final code is below for reference.

```
.btn-sq {
          width: 90px !important;
          height: 90px !important;
          font-size: 14px;
          background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
          margin: 5px;
          color:#000;
          white-space: normal;
          -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;

        }

        .btn-sq:hover {
          width: 90px !important;
          height: 90px !important;
          font-size: 14px;
          background-color:#C10000;
          margin: 5px;
          color:#fff;
          white-space: normal;
          -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
        }

        .btn-sq:focus {
          width: 90px !important;
          height: 90px !important;
          font-size: 14px;
          background-color:#C10000;
          margin: 5px;
          color:#fff;
          white-space: normal;
          -o-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          -ms-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          -moz-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          -webkit-transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
          transition:color .2s ease-out, background-color .2s ease-in;
        }       


<script>
    var myPlayer = document.getElementById('my_video_1');
    var myFunc = function(){
        var whereYouAt = myPlayer.currentTime; 
        if (whereYouAt > 1 && whereYouAt <= 10){
           var linkToFocus = document.getElementById('butt1');
           linkToFocus.focus();
           setInterval(function(){ linktoFocus.blur(); }, 4000);
        }
        else if (whereYouAt > 11){
           var linkToFocus = document.getElementById('butt1');
           linkToFocus.blur();
        }
    }
    myPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate',myFunc,false);
</script>
```